# Ravendb how to use Map Reducer

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

I have a 3-column table Id, Title, Section.

1. I want a unique value from the title column. ( which I fetch by Map Reduce index)
2. Now the user will select Title from the dropdown then want to fetch the Unique section which will match by Title (How to fetch unique section which match Title.  I use Distinct but performance get down)
3. Then the user will select the Section where I want to fetch Unique Title by matching the title and section

My Index

```
 class UniqueActIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<ActRuleModel, UniqueActIndex.Result> {
    public class Result {
        public string ActTitle { get; set; }
    }

    public UniqueActIndex() {
        Map = orders => from o in orders
                        select new Result {
                            ActTitle = Regex.Replace(o.ActTitle, @"[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", " ")
                        };

        Reduce = results => from r in results
                            group r by r.ActTitle into g
                            select new Result {
                                ActTitle = g.Key
                            };



    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

A Map-Reduce Index is usually used to aggregate data (at indexing time) which can later be queried on. 
See https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-reduce-index

You can also define a regular [Map Index](https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-index) and get the index **unique** '**Terms**' that are generated for the index. 
See https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/5.0/Csharp/client-api/operations/maintenance/indexes/get-terms